# Autocompletion in Eric IDE is not working

Tags: python, autocomplete, ide, eric-ide

I've installed Eric4.4.18 on Ubuntu from Ubuntu Software Center. I've marked the "Autocompletion Enabled" option and set the language to be python, but it's not working. All that Eric seems to do is syntax highlighting. How could I get it to work?